# Hive CLI not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

When I type "hive" command it hangs without going to hive prompt, when I checked logs I found below error.

```
ERROR [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread]: bonecp.PoolWatchThread (PoolWatchThread.java:fillConnections(118)) - Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 7000ms
java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
```

Can someone please suggest what am I missing here ?

Comment: possible replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747227/how-can-change-derby-to-read-write-mode

Answer (score 0):

Restart your derby database process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to derby database I changed it to PostgreSql and it worked!